# Facebook Graph API Posting a Comment as User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I am trying to build a comments method within a website without the Facebook comments plugin.

It's a photogallery portion of a website and all the photos are actually hosted on the business Page, I'm doing this to make use of FBs uploading, resizing/rotate etc rather than having to build that myself too.

As a happy bi-product to this I figured I could link comments on the website with comments on FB and have a syncrhonised comments system whereby comments posted on either site (my website or FB) will show equally on either site.

So, I have worked out how to post the comments, but it is always posting as the Business Page, not the logged in user.

This code posts the comment, the variable `obj` is the ID of the photo on Facebook. `msg` is obviously the comment text. I have setup methods to get the correct permissions where required which are called if the response from the post states that this is needed.

```
FB.api('/' + obj + '/comments',
     'post',
     { "message": msg,
       "access_token": accessToken,
       "from": uid
     }, // do the post
     function (response) { // check the response
                if (!response || response.error) { // if there's an error
          // DO STUFF WITH ERRORS/REQUEST PERMS ETC
     } else {
       alert("Msg posted id: " + response.id);
    };
});
```

Everything above works, but when the comment appears, it is always showing `from: my Page ID` not, what I need which would be `from: my user id`

`accessToken` and `UID` is being retrieved as follows:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
     }
 });
```

The para `from` in the first function there posts the User ID, NOT the page ID, but whether that para is there or not, it always posts the comment as the Page.

It's frustrating the hell out of me as so far this has been pretty simple to achieve!

Comment: Are you passing the page's access token or the access token for the user who you want to post the comment?

Comment: Well, that's possibly where I am getting lost. But the `access_token` is coming from the `FB.getLoginStatus` call, so that should be the User shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, the `FB.getLoginStatus` should be returning the user's access token and user ID, and your code looks good to me.

Comment: Doh!! I've just realised what I've been doing wrong... Nothing! But, as I'm admin for the page it's posting as page. Tried with a different user and its fine. Ooopps.... Nothing to see here!

Comment: Hey @JamieHartnoll, I am totally new to Facebook graphs API and finding a way to publish a comment to a public page post via graph api. can you please help me or provide some useful resources. thank you in advanced. (If the source of the project you doing so, is publicly available please provide me the like)